# Can iTunes on Mac, sync Music from Network Drives (NAS)?

Tags: networking, mac, sync, nas, itunes

I'm trying to buy a NAS adapter ([RAVPower Filehub Plus](https://www.ravpower.com/rp-wd03-filehub-6000mah-power-bank-portable-wireless-router.html)), and found that this device can be added as a network folder/drive on a Mac.

So, I'm thinking of using this network folder to sync music on iTunes, and am not sure if iTunes supports this sync method.

Does iTunes sync direct http/ftp links too? Maybe I could look for a network FTP server filehost for the same purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on how you qualify 'sync'. You can easily use it as the actual library file source for iTunes, but only one computer can actually be the 'master' for that library. If you want to use it for multiple machines either each would need its own independent library, or you'd be in for some tricksy management.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, a file source for iTunes! Was only wondering about syncing the music files to iPhone/iPod... Does iTunes allow adding music to iPhone via network drives? Wired/USB file sync is probably normal, although I've not tried syncing via network drive over WiFi.

Comment: iTunes would still be your 'master'. You can't do DIY OTA sync.

Comment: Ok. That helps! Could you post your first comment as an answer on this question's page, so that I can accept it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, if there's more than one user, you are going to set up each potential user's iTunes separately, then as soon as you migrate the Library to the external source you can continue to use it in exactly the same way as before.

If you let iTunes handle the file storage, using 'Keep Media folder organised' in Prefs >Advanced, then it should work the same as local storage.
There is plenty of documentation on how to move the Library - which essentially boils down to using 'Consolidate' to do the move for you [your safety copy until you have success is still on your local machine, so you can afford to test it out.]

I have my Library stored in a similar way - I have the remote volume always mounted, so it shows in /Volumes ...

[image]

BTW, always keep your 'main' iTunes folder on your local machine, only move the Library itself.

What you cannot do [without a deal of manual intervention] is use the same library for multiple users.

Though this QA is concerned with maintaining sync between Mac & Windows machines, exactly the same difficulties would arise if trying to maintain sync between 2 Mac users trying to share the same remote Library folder - I'd avoid it if you can.
[Ask Different - How to share an iTunes library between Mac & Windows?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230207/how-to-share-an-itunes-library-between-mac-windows)

***Note:*** I haven't tested any of this in iTunes 12.7, which at time of writing I only installed yesterday.